# Movie about an insane doctor and a haunted monastery

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv, horror

The movie is about a set of characters who I think go to a haunted monastery of some kind. They are also tortured killed off by an insane, red-headed doctor with scars on his face. I think the doctor himself may or may not be some kind of spirit, but one of the characters has some repressed traumatic past, which she is reminded of during her time in the monastery. The movie ends with that character out of the monastery, but someone who looks like the doctor (Maybe the doctor himself) walks by and makes some remarks to the character.

Update: I think that the traumatic past may be that, as a young girl, this character ended up shooting her father with a gun she happened to find. People in her life would tell her that her father died as a result of some accident, but she remembers that she intentionally shot him.

Comment: Roughly when did you watch this movie?

Comment: I don't remember. I reckon sometime after 2010, although the movie itself may or may not be older than that.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder whether you might be referring to the 1999 remake, *[House on Haunted Hill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/House_on_Haunted_Hill_(1999_film))*. It's not set in a monastery, but an asylum that also acted as a hospital, and there's stained glass present (especially in the one scene where it falls and nearly kills some of the guests). A recurring villain is the ghost of Dr. Vannacutt, who does not have red hair, but does sport scars, and the lighting of the movie, often incorporating red light, might make his hair look red.

[image: Dr. Richard B. Vannacutt]

> In 1931, the patients at the Vannacutt Psychiatric Institute for the Criminally Insane revolt against the staff headed by the sadistic Dr. Richard B. Vannacutt. The patients start a fire which engulfs the building, killing all of the inmates and all but five of Vannacutt’s staff.
>
> In 1999, Evelyn Stockard-Price is in a disintegrating marriage with Steven Price, an amusement park mogul. At Evelyn's insistence, Price stages her birthday party at the long-abandoned hospital. The building's owner, Watson Pritchett, is convinced it is evil, having lived there as a child when it was converted to a private residence. Five guests arrive for the party: film producer Jennifer Jenzen; baseball player Eddie Baker; former television personality Melissa Marr; Donald Blackburn, a physician; and Pritchett himself. The guests are not the ones Price invited and neither of the Prices know who they are. Despite this, Price continues the party's advertised theme, offering $1 million to each guest who remains in the house until morning; those who flee forfeit their $1 million to the others.

In a deleted scene, Dr. Vannacutt makes his return.

> A final epilogue scene completing the Jennifer Jenzen story arc was also filmed, featuring Jenzen arriving at the house with a realtor, which she was claimed to now inherited. As she enters the front door, a bloodcurdling scream is heard, and the realtor is revealed to be Dr. Vannacutt.

### Trailer

Comment: Nope, not the movie I'm looking for.